# How to compare columns in database table that have null values and display the ones without?

Tags: mysql, null

I'm having a form asking users to input their Staff ID and Student ID. 
So if i'm student, i will be prompted to enter my Student ID and vice versa.

Thus now in my database back-end, if the record showing staff, there will be 2 columns showing staff_id = "abcdef" while student_id = NULL.

Now i want to ask how to compare these 2 columns and display the one without NULL values.

Now my current codes that's not showing any results out nor any error:

```
$queryID = "Select student_id, user_id FROM ID";
$resultID = mysqli_query($link, $queryID) or die(mysqli_error($link));
<table>
<th>Student/ Staff</th>
<td><?php
                                                while ($rowID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultID)) {
                                                    $sid = $rowID['student_id'];
                                                    $uid = $rowID['user_id'];
                                                    if ($sid != null) {
                                                        $sid = $rowID['student_id'];
                                                        echo $sid;
                                                    } else {
                                                        $uid = $rowID['user_id'];
                                                        echo $uid;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ?></td></table>
```

Please advice and help. Thanks.

Comment: `IS (NOT) NULL`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: But i want both the student_id and user_id to be displayed under the table just that if 1 column is not null, it will display out the id whereas if null, it will display as NULL.

Comment: By the way, your question's code contains purely injected HTML here. if that's your real code.

Comment: I've tried many ways for this. Okay thanks, i will go read up on that article to find out more about NULL functions. Really thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions, but I would change the query to:

```
Select IFNULL(student_id, user_id) as ID,
       CASE WHEN student_id IS NULL THEN 'User'
                                    ELSE 'Student'
       END as Type
FROM   ID
```

The `CASE WHEN ... Type` is optional, in case you still want to know what kind of `id` you are getting.

Then you can get the `id` and `type` in your loop, as follows:

```
...
$id = $rowID['id']; // for either student or user
$type = $rowID['type']; // either "User" or "Student"
```

and you don't need the `if` statement any more.

I added the variable `$type`, as you still might want to know which of the two it is, but if you just need to display this one column, you don't really need it.

So, after fixing some other issues with missing `tr` tags, and assuming you don't need `$type`, you get this:

```
$queryID = "Select IFNULL(student_id, user_id) as ID FROM ID";
$resultID = mysqli_query($link, $queryID) or die(mysqli_error($link));
<table>
    <tr><th>Student/ Staff</th></tr>
    <?php
        while ($rowID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultID)) {
            echo "<tr><td>{$rowID['id']}</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `is_null` or `!==` operator :-

```
if (! is_null($sid)) {
$sid = $rowID['student_id'];
echo $sid;
}
```